# How does dropout work in keras' LSTM layer?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

In keras' [documentation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) there is no information regarding how dropout is actually implemented for LSTM layers.

However, there is a link to the paper "[A Theoretically Grounded Application of Dropout in Recurrent Neural Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.05287)", which led me to believe that dropout is implemented as described in said paper.

That is, for each time-step in the time-series the layer is processing, the same dropout mask is used.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py), it seems to me that [LSTMCell.call](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1847) gets called iteratively, once for every time-step in the time-series, and generates a new dropout mask each time it is called.

My question is:

Either I misinterpreted keras' code, or the reference to the paper in keras' documentation is misleading. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the paper and the code are consistent. You have understood correctly but interpreted the code a bit wrong.

There is a check before initialising dropout_mask, `self._dropout_mask is None`

So LSTMCell.call gets called iteratively, once for every time-step in the time-series, but only in the first call a new dropout mask is generated.

```
if 0 < self.dropout < 1 and self._dropout_mask is None:
    self._dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
        K.ones_like(inputs),
        self.dropout,
        training=training,
        count=4)
if (0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1 and
        self._recurrent_dropout_mask is None):
    self._recurrent_dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
        K.ones_like(states[0]),
        self.recurrent_dropout,
        training=training,
        count=4)
```

Hope that clarifies your doubt.

Comment: That absolutely answers my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome @PhillipJayDoe :) If it's not much effort please accept (tick) the answer and upvote (if you want to), Thanks :)